# How to use small SSD drive on server?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2

I just launched m3.medium instance on Amazon AWS with SSD drive 4GB capacity. However I installed system, system apps and /var on regular EBS.

I'm wondering now how can I use this 4GB SSD which is not used right now. What do you think would be nice to have on low-latency, fast-save disk drive?

What I'm currently using on my server instance:

- Apache2 + PHP5
- MySQL
- Atlassian applications (with their own Tomcat servers)
- Git server
- Ldap server

How about SWAP?

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to put the MySQL data on the drive, and/or the files for your web apps. Those are all fairly disk intensive (mysql the most disk taxing) and all would benefit from the extra speed.

Comment: Unfortunately this SSD is ephemeral drive so it can't have any important data. But I was thinking a lot about moving sql to this drive. Maybe there is some way to boost regular MySQL with some kind of cache on SSD? Sort of plugin? Never heard of things like that, but maybe...?

Answer (score 0):

You can use enhanceIO to cache anything in your SSD: https://github.com/stec-inc/EnhanceIO

Swap is not a bad idea although, you've got to check how much RAM memory you are using on your server. If you are not close to maxing it out, then swap does you no good. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0):

Using it for swap is a bad idea.  If you need more RAM, get a bigger instance.  SSDs may be fast, but they aren't nearly as fast as actual RAM.  If you need MySQL cache, use ElastiCache (since you're already on AWS.)  This will likely be faster than that SSD.

For your use case, I don't see a use for the SSD.  If you were retrieving a file (audio, video, photo) from S3 for conversion, this would be a good place to store it while you were processing it.

Comment: Why is using it for swap a bad idea? That's probably the best option.

Comment: For their use case, it probably IS the best option.  But if you're paging, even to an SSD, that's a sign that you need a bigger instance.

Comment: You're guys both right. I used it as a swap. Right now - 0% usage. I'll wait for all Atlassian apps running and then check if maybe they'll use some of it. I guess Jenkins will like it too.